# Find index of NaN in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, nan

```
[1, 2, 3].indexOf(3) => 2

[1, 2, NaN].indexOf(NaN) => -1

[1, NaN, 3].indexOf(NaN) => -1
```

Comment: You can use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) if you just want to know **if an array includes a `NaN`**: `[NaN].includes(NaN) /* true */`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method to find out the index of NaN in an array

```js
let index = [1,3,4,'hello',NaN,3].findIndex(Number.isNaN)
console.log(index)
```

You can  use [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if NaN is present in an array or not. It won't give you the index though !! It will return a boolean value. If NaN is present true will be returned, otherwise false will be returned

```js
let isNaNPresent = [1,2,NaN,'ball'].includes(NaN)
console.log(isNaNPresent)
```

**Don't use `Array.prototype.indexOf`**

You can not use [Array.Prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find index of [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) inside an array.Because indexOf uses [strict-equality-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) internally and **`NaN === NaN`** evaluates to **`false`**.So indexOf won't be able to detect NaN inside an array

```
[1,NaN,2].indexOf(NaN) // -1
```

**Use `Number.isNaN` instead of `isNaN` :**

Here i choose  [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) over [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN). Because `isNaN` treats `string literal` as `NaN`.On the other hand `Number.isNaN` treats only `NaN` literal as `NaN`

```
isNaN('hello world') // true
Number.isNaN('hello world') // false
```

***Or, Write your own logic :***

You can write your own logic to find NaN.As you already know that, NaN is the only value in javascript which is `not equal to itself`. That's the reason i suggested not to use `Array.prototype.indexOf`.

```
NaN === NaN // false
```

We can use this idea to write our own isNaN function.

```
[1,2,'str',NaN,5].findIndex(e=>e!=e) // 3
```

Comment: Would it not be clearer here to just pass in the isNaN function? Also `findIndex` is available in more implementations than arrow functions, so all it's doing is reducing the portability of this answer.

Comment: @WillS i have modified my answer

Answer (score 13):

NaN is defined not to be equal to anything (not even itself). See here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isNaN.asp

Comment: Will upvote and accept when my timer runs out. That's just retarded.

Comment: Explain that to the IEEE; it's their floating point standard that defines `NaN` to not be equal to anything.  (That said, think of it as `NULL` in RDBMSes.)

Comment: -1 is also used as an error value. Would it make any sense for -1 != -1 ?

Comment: @mcandre, it's _not_ retarded. The whole point of NaN is to represent things that are considered not representable in the domain. That's not _one_ type of thing, it's many. For example, you cannot possibly say that the square root of -1, `i`, is the same as zero divided by itself (indeterminate). Yet they are both NaNs.

Comment: I get that. I do. But from a practical standpoint, if I want to, say,  extract all the NaNs from an array, it would be useful to compare elements to NaN rather than having to call isNaN().

Answer (score 2):

You have to look at each item to return an array 
of the indexes that are NaN values-

```
function findNaNs(arr){
    return arr.map(function(itm, i){
        if(isNaN(itm)) return i;
        return false;
    }).filter(function(itm){
        return itm;
    });
}
```

findNaNs([1, NaN, 3, 4, 'cat'/3])

//or to find the first one-

```
function firstNaN(arr){
    var i= 0, L= arr.length;
    while(i<L){
        if(isNaN(arr[i])) return i;
        ++i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, kennebec. It's not hard to code around this problem, just inconvenient.

Comment: Never use `isNaN`, it's broken. It implicitly coerces value type. You get `true` for `isNaN(undefined)`, `isNaN({})` (but not `isNaN([])`), etc. Use comparison to itself instead: `x !== x` (`NaN` is the only value that doesn't equal self).

Comment: The first routine cannot find NaN if it is the first element.